# Find key of nested object and return its path

Tags: javascript, json, object, path-finding

Does anyone know a good javascript npm package (or have some good function) to find a JSON key and return its path (or paths if key exists more than once in nested JSON)

```
for example:
var person={
"name":myName,
"address":{
"city",
"location":{
"long":123,
"lat":456
}
"long"
```

I want to use a function that will return the path to this key, in above example the key "long" exist twice:

`console.log(getKeyPath(person,"long");`
//address.long , long

Comment: Recursion check to loop over the objects and store the path, when you find it, return the path... what happens if there are multiple keys that would match?

Comment: You're looking for a depth-first search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`obj-flatten`](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/obj-flatten) you can make that a flat object:

```
var person = {
  "name": "your name"
  "location.long": 123,
  "location.lat": 456,
  "long": 42,
  ...
}
```

And then you simply have to query by that pattern:

```
var searchKey = "long";
var yourKeys = Object.keys(person).filter(function (c) {
   return c.split(".").indexOf(searchKey) !== -1;
});
// => ["location.long", "long"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Native javascript is always recommended if you are learning the language but you can use the lodash library. 
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#at

Read some methods like _.at(), _.has(), or _.findKey()