# Find paths to all keys in an object that match a given string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object with repeated key names at various depths. I would like to write a function (plain JS) that returns an array of paths to **all** keys that match a given name.

For example:

```
const obj = {
    stuff: {
        A: 'text'
    },
    deeperStuff: {
        nested: {
            A: ['data']
        }
    }
};

const func = (object, key) => {
    ...
};

console.log(func(obj, 'A'));
// [['stuff', 'A'], ['deeperStuff', 'nested', 'A']]
```

Apologies if this is a duplicate question but I couldn't find an answer that fitted my needs.

Thanks in advance,

P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find key of nested object and return its path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267696/find-key-of-nested-object-and-return-its-path)

Comment: Those solutions look like they would work but I'd prefer a plain JS solution

Comment: Read comments under that question attentively.

Comment: I still couldn't see a plain JS solution. Pherris' answer has hit the mark on this question though so I have accepted it

Comment: That was a clue, not a solution. Solutions are posted in answers, not comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this... take the object and loop through its keys looking for a match.  If we find one, add to a hash (I changed the output type).  If the value is another object, recurse with that nested object.

```js
const myObj = {
    stuff: {
        A: 'text'
    },
    deeperStuff: {
        nested: {
            A: ['data']
        }
    }
};

function findKeys(obj, desiredKey, path = [], results = {}) {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj)
  keys.forEach(function(key) {
    const currentPath = path.concat([key])
    if (key === desiredKey) {
      results[currentPath.join('/')] = obj[key]
    } 
    if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
      findKeys(obj[key], desiredKey, currentPath, results)
    }
  })
  return results
}

// same functionality with your desired return type
function findKeyArray(obj, desiredKey, path = [], results = []) {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj)
  keys.forEach(function(key) {
    const currentPath = path.concat([key])
    if (key === desiredKey) {
      results.push(currentPath); // changed this line
    } 
    if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
      findKeyArray(obj[key], desiredKey, currentPath, results); // and this line ;)
    }
  })
  return results
}

console.log(findKeys(myObj, "A"))
console.log(findKeyArray(myObj, "A"))
```

outputs

```
{
  deeperStuff/nested/A: ["data"],
  stuff/A: "text"
}

[["stuff", "A"], ["deeperStuff", "nested", "A"]]
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. Out of curiosity, why did you decide upon a different output type? I was intending to later execute a function on each match (or sometimes on the parent of each match) so iterating over an array of array of keys seemed the simplest approach to me.

Comment: I thought it was easier to illustrate the nested path with a hash.  The data is there for the desired output type - will do a quick edit to return the array format.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach without storing the actual visited path for the result.

```js
function getDeeperPath(object, key) {
    return Object
        .entries(object)
        .reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
            if (k === key) {
                return r.concat(k);
            }
            if (v && typeof v === 'object') {
                getDeeperPath(v, key).forEach(t => r.push([k, ...t]));
            }
            return r;
        }, []);
}

const object = { stuff: { A: 'text' }, deeperStuff: { nested: { A: ['data'] } } };

console.log(getDeeperPath(object, 'A'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). Concise and allows for complex patterns in the search path, but you are adding a dependency - so there is a trade-off here.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const myObj = { stuff: { A: 'text' }, deeperStuff: { nested: { A: ['data'] } } };

console.log(objectScan(['**.A'])(myObj));
// => [ [ 'deeperStuff', 'nested', 'A' ], [ 'stuff', 'A' ] ]

console.log(objectScan(['**.stuff.A'])(myObj));
// => [ [ 'stuff', 'A' ] ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)