# Get recursive path from object keys and map it with the last node value

Tags: typescript

Ok, a little edit of question.

I do have an object:

```
export const sectionsTree: SectionRoot = {
    [RouteEnum.PROJECTS]: {
        [SubRouteEnum.EMPTY]: {
            moduleName: ModuleEnum.ProjectsList,
            onAction: {
                [ActionEnum.SELECT_PROJECT]: ModuleEnum.ActiveProjectFormsList
            }
        },
        [SubRouteEnum.PARAM_PROJECT_ID]: {
            [SubRouteEnum.FORMS]: {
                moduleName: ModuleEnum.ActiveProjectFormsList,
                displayAsTabView: true,
                onAction: {
                    [ActionEnum.SELECT_PROJECT_FORM]: ModuleEnum.ActiveProjectForm
                },
                [SubRouteEnum.PARAM_FORM_ID]: {
                    moduleName: ModuleEnum.ActiveProjectForm
                }
            },
            [SubRouteEnum.ATTRIBUTES]: {
                moduleName: ModuleEnum.ActiveProjectAttributesList,
                displayAsTabView: true,
                onAction: {
                    [ActionEnum.SELECT_PROJECT_ATTRIBUTE]: ModuleEnum.ActiveProjectAttribute
                },
                [SubRouteEnum.PARAM_ATTRIBUTE_ID]: {
                    moduleName: ModuleEnum.ActiveProjectAttribute
                }
            }
        }
    },
    [RouteEnum.MEASUREMENTS_UNITS]: {
        [SubRouteEnum.EMPTY]: {
            moduleName: ModuleEnum.MeasurementUnitsTable,
            onAction: {
                [ActionEnum.MANAGE_MEASUREMENT_UNIT]: ModuleEnum.ManageMeasurementUnit
            }
        },
        [SubRouteEnum.PARAM_MEASUREMENT_UNIT_ID]: {
            moduleName: ModuleEnum.ManageMeasurementUnit,
            onAction: {
                [ActionEnum.SAVE_MEASUREMENT_UNIT]: ModuleEnum.MeasurementUnitsTable
            }
        }
    }
};
```

From it, I need to get all paths that leads to moduleName properties and pair them with the values of each moduleName, where in example it would be an array or object of such keys-values:

```
[ModuleEnum.ActiveProjectAttribute]: ":id/attributes/:attributeid"
```

Also as you can see, I don't want to keep the first key, which would be RouteEnum.PROJECTS. However if even, it will be easy for me to remove it as it will be always first element of each path that goes from RouteEnum.PROJECTS root.

Comment: Missing some definitions...

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see the issue.  Missing declarations or other problems unrelated to your issue just make it harder or impossible for us to help.  Also it would be helpful if your [mre] contained some test input/output including their types.  Like, do you want the property types just to be `string` or do you need them to be string literal types?  A clear criterion for success would help us help you.

Comment: I've edited question to simplify the goal which also simplifies needed data. Object tree can be anything to make some tests. You can make any enum as you want or whatever keys. Hope it will be easier and won't leave unanswered stuff.

Comment: Found answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52832858/find-paths-to-all-keys-in-an-object-that-match-a-given-string in @pherris comment